# React-native-sound creates infinite loop

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I'm using react-native-sound library in order to play one track multiple times. Here is my code:

```
 const playAudio = () => {
   sound.setNumberOfLoops(2).play()
 }

playAudio()
```

I wonder why the track is played infinite times.

Answer (score 0):

The `playAudio()` shouldn’t be  used directly. Use this

```
useEffect( () => {
   playAudio()
}, [] )

const playAudio = () => {
   // Loop indefinitely until stop() is called
   sound.setNumberOfLoops(-1).play()
}
```

Comment: Like this it doesn't play at all. I tried using a button and it creates infinite loop.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Try that.

Comment: sound.setNumberOfLoops(2).play()  works the same way as  sound.setNumberOfLoops(-1).play(). I need to play the track just twice but it doesn't stop automatically. I don't want infinite loop.